# Elasticsearch skips @-symbol

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have a custom analyzer with provided char filter:

```
"char_filter": {
     "hash_repl": {
         "pattern": "(^[^\\#@].+)",
         "type": "pattern_replace",
         "preserve_original": "false",
         "replacement": "$1 #$1 @$1"
      }
  }
```

When I'm sending POST request for testing analyzer, I'm waiting for behaviour like:

```
a => a #a @a
#a => #a
@a => @a
```

The problem is that elastic doesn't render "@" symbol in responses and usually I get

```
a => a #a a
#a => #a
@a => a
```

Comment: Try the usual things: 1) add ``\\`` before @, 2) try duplicating the `@`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution was easy. My custom analyzer also contains several char filters and token filters. The problem was solved by adding custom mappings:

```
"char_filter": {
    "custom": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": [
            "#=>|#"
        ]
      }
},
"filter": {
    "custom": {
        "type": "word_delimiter",
        "type_table": [
            "# => ALPHA",
            "@ => ALPHA"
         ],
         "split_on_numerics": "false"
     }
}
```